# Kurtosis of a straddle

Tags: options, black-scholes, distribution, moments

I want to determine the kurtosis of a straddle. My question is closely related with the following topic [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30138/variance-of-a-straddle-black-scholes).
According to the following paper of [Ben-Meir and Schiff (2012)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.3452.pdf) the expected value of a call is equal to

[image]

where

[image]

The variance of the call is

[image]

Following the standard definition of kurtosis I can write:

[image]

Similar, I can write the same for the puts:

[image]

Is it correct to assume that:

[image: I want to calculate the kurtosis of a straddle]

Comment: No it is not. For the same reason you cannot assume the variance of a portfolio equals the sum of the of the individual variances. And it's even weird to talk about variance of a call/putinstead of variance of the return of a call/put. This may help: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/calculating-portfolio-skewness-kurtosis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you assume null [cokurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cokurtosis) terms, your equality is still off:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Kurt}[X+Y] = {1 \over \sigma_{X+Y}^4} \big( & \sigma_X^4\operatorname{Kurt}[X] + \sigma_Y^4\operatorname{Kurt}[Y] \big).
\end{align}

Note that you need $\sigma_{X+Y}^2$. You already have $\sigma_X^2$ and $\sigma_Y^2$ (computed in the paper).

Full formula is:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Kurt}[X+Y] = {1 \over \sigma_{X+Y}^4} \big( & \sigma_X^4\operatorname{Kurt}[X] + 4\sigma_X^3\sigma_Y\operatorname{Cokurt}[X,X,X,Y] \\
& {} + 6\sigma_X^2\sigma_Y^2\operatorname{Cokurt}[X,X,Y,Y] \\[6pt]
& {} + 4\sigma_X\sigma_Y^3\operatorname{Cokurt}[X,Y,Y,Y] + \sigma_Y^4\operatorname{Kurt}[Y] \big).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks do you think it is reasonable to assume null cokurtosis terns?